# How thread is preserved in os fork?

Tags: operating-system, multiprocess

I want to check whether thread will be preserved during `os.fork`.
This is what the thread is started before `os.fork`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import multiprocessing
from threading import Timer
import time

i = [0]

def work():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        i[0] += 1
        print i[0]
        print multiprocessing.current_process()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    task = Timer(1, work)
    task.daemon = True
    task.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'pre fork'
    if os.fork():
        # parent process
    else:
        # child process
        multiprocessing.current_process().name = "Secondary"
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'post fork'
    time.sleep(1000)
```

The output of this program:

```
pre fork
1
<_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
2
<_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
post fork
post fork
3
<_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
4
<_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
5
<_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
6
<_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
7
<_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
```

==========================================================================

This is what the thread is started after `os.fork`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import multiprocessing
from threading import Timer
import time

i = [0]

def work():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        i[0] += 1
        print i[0]
        print multiprocessing.current_process()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    task = Timer(1, work)
    task.daemon = True
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'pre fork'
    if os.fork():
        # parent process
        task.start()
    else:
        # sub process
        multiprocessing.current_process().name = "Secondary"
        task.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'post fork'
    time.sleep(1000)
```

The output is like this:

```
pre fork
post fork
post fork
1
1
<_MainProcess(Secondary, started)>
<_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
2
2
<_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
<_MainProcess(Secondary, started)>
```

Summary

- It seems that when we start the thread after `os.fork` then every thing will be ok and both the parent and child process will run the thread.
- When we start the thread before `os.fork`, then according to the output, it seems that the thread is not come up with `os.fork`, i.e., it is not executed in the child process.

The question is how should this happen and what is the reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly, i come up with an explanation and the answer is **No, thread will no be preserved during `os.fork`**.

- `os.fork` only do a copy-on-write.
- parent and child process both have the same code.
- However, if we start a thread before `os.fork`, then there no `start` logic to child process.
- So, if we want a thread exist in child process then we can only start it after we have `os.fork` it.

:)

**Note: This has some similar with [gunicorn --preload argument](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#preload-app).**